# IllegalStateException: Populating ehCache with JSON Object via HttpClient using POST

Tags: java, json, jersey, httpclient, ehcache

Am using Java 6, Tomcat 7, Jersey, HttpClient, with ehCache Server.

Registered a new cache by the name of ipad inside $CATALINA_HOME/ehcache/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache.xml

```
<cache name="ipad"
           maxElementsInMemory="10000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO"
/>
```

This is what my Client looks like:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class EhCachePostClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
            String jsonString = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

            // Post the same object to ehCache
            DefaultHttpClient ehCacheClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String ehCacheResponseString =
    EhCacheClientHelper.getEhCacheJsonResponseString(ehCacheClient, jsonString);
            System.out.println("\nFrom ehCache Server: " + ehCacheResponseString);
            ehCacheClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

Here's the EhCacheClientHelper class (where majority of the work is done):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class EhCacheClientHelper {

    private static final String EHCACHE_IPAD_URI 
                   = "http//localhost:8080/ehcache/rest/ipad";

    public static String getEhCacheJsonResponseString(
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient, String responseString) 
    throws Exception {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(EHCACHE_MDS_URI);

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(responseString);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " 
                     + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        StringBuilder ehCacheOutput = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("\nOutput from ehCache Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ehCacheOutput.append(output);
        }
        return ehCacheOutput.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:784)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.myapp.client.EhCacheClientHelper.getEhCacheJsonResponseString(EhCacheClientHelper.java:22)
    at com.myapp.client.EhCachePostClient.main(EhCachePostClient.java:19)
```

What am I doing wrong?

All I want to do is create a sample cache in ehCache, post some type of JSON object to it, and then retrieve it using curl command.

Is this a hard thing to do? What am I missing (in terms of implementation, configuration, etc.)?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Answer (score 2):

You have:

> http//...

Should be:

> http://...

You miss ":"

Comment: Thanks Chris, but after fixing the URL by adding in the : (colon), I get this new exception:                                      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 405
 at com.myapp.client.EhCacheClientHelper.getEhCacheJsonResponseString(EhCacheClientHelper.java:27)
 at com.myapp.client.EhCachePostClientApp.main(EhCachePostClientApp.java:21)

Comment: Http 405 means: method not allowed.